# How to do to see my AdMob Ads?

Tags: android, admob

i tryed ALL CODES FROM ALL THE WORLD and i got 2 things: 1) errors or 2)Don´t see ads..

**This is my Manifest:**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.adview.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
   </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

***UPDATED!!!!***
**This is my *NEW* Layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"       
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxx" i put my editor id here..
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And... 
**This is my class** (i dont put anything because i did it in layout)

```
package com.example.adview;



import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**I put the GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1 (The latest version) in libs AND in Project>RightClick>Properties>JavaBuildPath>AddExternalJARs>GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in main activity layout.xml have you added this

```
xmlns:ads= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

and you have to add tihs line to your ad code

`ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"`

Comment: Ok, but don´t works D:
My layout look like this:

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"       
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    
I will put so much comments because i can´t put full code D:

Comment: android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

Comment: <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adUnitId="a152915638b0b40"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

</RelativeLayout>

@Jack K Fouani

Comment: I don´t see the ads on my phone or in the simulator.. In my layout i always saw it.
@Jack K Fouani

Comment: please update your question with full code , and check in admob is ur app sending data like its sending requests to admob

Comment: Yes i am receiving data... http://imageshack.com/a/img4/3103/mdp0.jpg
And.. i updated the Layout :D
But.. i don´t see ads yet D:

Comment: LOL, wait D:
I don´t see the ads yet.. But because i need more space, Logcat detect that i don´t have sufficient space (320 x 50) and i have 288 x (i cant remember ) XD
How can i put the banner for 320 x 50 ?
Thanks and sorry for all my questions :D

UPDATE: I fixed it.. was for a Margin in the layout. THANKS, LOVE YOU! :D

Answer (score 0):

You either need to add this to your AdView

```
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
```

or you need to programmatically load your add from your Activity (I'd suggest in the onCreate).

```
final AdView adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
adView.load(new AdRequest());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    ... Other View 

</LinearLayout>

LinearLayout ad_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ad_layout);
ad_layout.setOrientation( LinearLayout.VERTICAL );

mAdView = new AdView(this);
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
mAdView.setAdUnitId( UNIT_ID );

AdRequest.Builder adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder();
adRequest.addTestDevice( AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR );
adRequest.addTestDevice( "3204995868e01153" );
adRequest.addTestDevice( "b9ceca537aaddee2" );

ad_layout.addView( mAdView );

mAdView.loadAd( adRequest.build() );
```